# Is the fixnum library available for testing?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to port the Wavpack audio decoder in my freetime to Dart and it requires fixed numeric types and just saw that the Dart SDK has a new library called 'fixnum' which will possibly fit my needs: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/fixnum.html

As i see not even the bleeding edge Dart builds contain this library. Is it possible to fetch it from somewhere? Maybe it's still very raw right now and not really useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other sdk libraries (*args*, *intl*, *logging*, *meta*, *serialization*, *unittest*) *matcher*, *mock* and *fixnum* are not available in [pub](http://pub.dartlang.com). I don't really know why, but they should IMHO. [A comment on issue 7540](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7540#c6) reports that *fixnum* is missing but feel free to [fill a new issue](http://dartbug.com/new) for that.

Once on [pub](http://pub.dartlang.com), you will be able to use *fixnum* with the following dependency in your *pubspec.yaml* :

```yaml
dependencies:
  fixnum: any
```

Comment: Thanks. I've found it's source files on Github: https://github.com/kevmoo/dart-repo/blob/master/lib/fixnum/fixnum.dart I guess i can clone it to my SDK instance till it's officially released. I hope there will be a pub dependency for it soon.